# Sentence with 5 letter words

Tags: language, english

Can you make a sentence only using words of exactly five letters?
It must be a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: What counts as a grammatically correct sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hello Green World, Enjoy These Fresh Baked Cream Cakes Again Today

Answer (score 2):

Yes, very easily: "Lions slept" is one such sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a puzzle though...

But here's one:

> Those women stood there.